# onbeforeunload works only if developer tool window is active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

As title, I have this piece of code in my AngularJS project:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($sessionStorage.toReload) {
      return 'Are you sure?';
    }
  };
```

It works correctly if developer tool window is open, but it doesn't during normal execution. It happens both in Chrome and Firefox.

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you create a plunkr and share demo code there ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of a really big project. I'm not sure it would have the same outcome

Comment: From the docs for `onbeforeunload` event: `Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of specific browsers, see the Browser_compatibility section.` So if I click buttons, or other UI elements in chrome it will work. But if I just open the page and close it again without doing anything, I don't get a popup.

Comment: It really helped me understanding the issue, thanks. Is there any way I can simulate an interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the documentation page has the answer:

> Note also, that various browsers ignore the result of the event and do
> not ask the user for confirmation at all. In such cases, the document
> will always be unloaded automatically. Firefox has a switch named
> dom.disable_beforeunload in about:config to enable this behavior. As
> of Chrome 60, the confirmation will be skipped if the user has not
> performed a gesture in the frame or page since it was loaded. **Pressing
> F5 in the page seems to count as user interaction, whereas
> mouse-clicking the refresh arrow or pressing F5 with Chrome DevTools
> focused does not count as user interaction (as of Chrome 81).**